# Does anyone know what character ⿰彳⿱㚘心 is?

Tags: character-identification

Someone asked me for help with this character.  I could not write it down on my keyboard with handwriting, so I looked through my dictionary the old fashioned way for it (Pleco).

[image]

I looked at every single entry for the radical 心, and did not see it.  I also did not see anything similar enough to be a recognizable typo (everything I saw would have required at least two of the four radicals to be wrong). I even looked through the unicode characters in Pleco with no definition, no luck.

There is always the chance that it is grossly miswritten, but it looks like it could be a perfectly correct character.
So of all the remaining possibilities I considered, I find it most likely to be one of the characters that never made it into the 20,000+ unicode characters.

I think it would be possible to check in one of the much bigger pre computer age dictionaries, but have no way to get a hold of one here in the USA.

Does someone have access to such a dictionary, or recognize the character?

Does anyone have an alternate way to find it, or look up such non unicode characters?

Comment: As far as I can tell, [it is not encoded](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/char?fontcode=10.E8D5). [Similar characters](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/ytz_33057x.html) do exist [but they](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/ytz_33056z.html) are not the same.

Comment: @dROOOze good to confirm that it is indeed a non-unicode character.  Any idea a way to check the meaning/what the regular version is? I checked your two links but did not see that info. (maybe I missed it I haven't used either before.)

Comment: I forgot to mention - you should not be using radicals to check characters (that's very inefficient). Try http://www.guoxuedashi.net/zidian/bujian/ which is how I found those entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely, that's a variant of 愆 (U+6106)/ (U+2039D) 'fault, mistake, error, transgression'. In fact, [GlyphWiki](https://glyphwiki.org/wiki/cbeta-15523) records exactly the variant under question as 'cbeta-15523', [CBETA](https://cbetaonline.dila.edu.tw/) being the digital archive of the Buddhist Canon, so this form has definitely been seen around somewhere in the Buddhist maniscripts.

Answer (score 0):

It’s shown here in this dictionary:

[https://www.zdic.net/hant/](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%F0%A0%8E%9D)